# mod_rewrite Redirecting to last part of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect http://127.0.0.1/upload/load/1/www.google.com 
to
www.google.com

Where http://127.0.0.1/upload/load/ remains same for every url and last part /1/www.google.com changes to /2/www.amazon.com/ , /3/www.aol.com and so on.

I tried doing this but its giving me redirect loop error. 
My htaccess file looks like this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin$ Admin/index.php?qstr=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

Updated htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^upload/load/[0-9]+/(.*)$ http://$1 [NC,L,R]
```

I think the rule which you said to comment out was the rule which was allow my files to work. May this is the reason. So I must have to keep that rule .

My further updated htaccess after adding rewrite log code ( and this showing internal server error)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

# Roll your own Rewrite log
# Log details via scale of 1 to 9
# 1 = few details, 5 = enough details, 9 = too much detail
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog “d:/wamp/rewrite.log”
RewriteLogLevel 5


RewriteRule ^upload/load/[0-9]+/(.*)$ http://$1 [NC,L,R]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^upload/load/[0-9]+/(.*)$ http://$1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

However I have to say this that your question statement and your attempted rules don't match at all.

Comment: Sir its not working. Showing redirect loop error. not sure whats wrong with this.

Comment: You have to comment out all of your existing RedirectRule first. And keep in mind this rule is to `redirect http://127.0.0.1/upload/load/1/www.google.com to http://www.google.com`

Comment: I tried that also , still not working. Its now showing The requested URL /upload/load/1/www.google.com was not found on this server.

Comment: I have already tested that rule and it is working fine on my Apache. Most likely you have some conflicting rule or your .htaccess is not even being read. Pls provide your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Ok got it, you can keep your existing `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]` but keep my suggested as the first rule in your .htaccess file as in my updated answer.

Comment: Problem is still the same. Showing redirect loop error. Followed what you said. Still the same.

Comment: All the rules suggested above, I have tried them on my end and are working great. You need to enable RewriteLog and provide the matching lines from that log here.

Comment: See here: http://www.bestdesigns.co.in/blog/create-apache-rewrite-log-file

Comment: When I am adding this code (with my absolute url) in htaccess file and then opening 127.0.0.1/upload its showing internal server error. I am using wamp.

Comment: Make sure your .htaccess is working and in any case provide me RewriteLog content to help you better.

Comment: I am getting internal server error and no rewrite log is generated in my folder whose url i mentioned. Check i have updated my current htaccess in above code.

Comment: I checked you latest .htaccess and there is a problem. RewriteLog related stuff goes to httpd.conf not in .htaccess once you move this stuff to .htaccess and restart the apache then do your testing and post your results.

Comment: I added rewriteLog stuff in httpd.conf and restarted my server and strange to see that its not getting started. When i again remove RewriteLog stuff its working fine. I added 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog “D:/wamp/rewrite.log”
RewriteLogLevel 5`
I tried putting these lines at many places in my httpd.conf and server not restarting after that.

Comment: Pls start looking into your error.log. If Apache isn't starting it should be writing some errors there.

Comment: `[Tue Jan 24 15:24:28 2012] [error] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: mod_rewrite: Invalid RewriteLog path \x93D:/wamp/rewrite.txt\x94
Configuration Failed`
This is the error i am getting

Comment: Solved this error of path. Problem was with fancy double quotes `RewriteLog “d:/wamp/rewrite.log”` as i copied.But now when i restart my server a new file is created namely httpd.pid which have a random number in it. and when i open localhost is not opening.

Comment: My apache error log : http://pastebin.com/rG2Pn1Xu
This is after i have entered RewriteLog stuff in httpd.conf and server is not starting and showing on website as : The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted.

Comment: Your Apache error log appears fine now and Apache process would be running, you can check `Task Manager`. For the error you're getting `The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted` you should see something in your error.log as well.

Comment: Reason is obviously the rewritelog file i have added because as soon as i remove them i dint get any error.

Comment: error.log? where is that? is this different from what i posted in pastebin?

Comment: What you posted is indeed error.log. That file should have something for the error `The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted`. Pls understand in the absence of RewriteLog I won't be able to investigate it since I don't what is causing looping problem on your side since those rules are perfectly fine and working on my XAMPP installation.

Comment: Sir i understand completely. Check this is what all i get in my error log. http://pastebin.com/b9gmMvH7